# how to insert a custom string between two double array dimensions

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have an array called `temp` containing `double`-precision values with dimensions 240×20×10428 . I would like to write it to a text file. I tried the following:

```
dlmwrite(['e:\temp\', str, '.txt'], temp, 'precision', 10);
```

now the problem is how to add `\r\n\r\n` string(two enter pressed key) after each first dimension (we have 240th of this dimension) in the text file? what should I have done? I want to have this format after all:

```
0.324235,...(20*10428 numbers),0.4363423,\r\n\r\n,
0.5467354,...(20*10428 numbers),0.346564,...
```

NOTE: this array come from `.nc` files and I want to convert them into `.txt` file using this way

Answer (score 2):

The handy-dandy canned routines that ship with MATLAB are actually quite limited when it comes to customizability. Whenever you have some file writing to do with a custom format, it comes in handy to know how to do it yourself:

```
% Open file for writing, safely
fid = fopen(fullfile('e:\temp\', str, '.txt'), 'w');
OC  = onCleanup(@() any(fopen('all')==fid) && fclose(fid));

% Simply loop through all rows
for ii = 1:size(temp,1)

    % Format the numbers, with comma as separator
    line = sprintf('%.10f,', temp(ii,:)); % (trick to concatenate last dimension into second one)
    line(end) = []; %(remove last comma)

    % Print this line, adding two PC-type newlines
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n\r\n', line);
end

% Clean up
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Isn't a _function_ required so that `onCleanup` is actually executed?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for pointing that out. AFAIK, `onCleanup`'s main functionality is in its destructor, so the cleanup action is run whenever that `OC` variable goes out of scope. So: yes, it should be inside a function :) (or manually cleared). I just have included in my AutoHotkey snippet, because I hardly ever write elaborate scripts, mostly functions.